# List the files with name in Amazon Glacier vault

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

Can we list the files with name in Amazon Glacier vault without help of any software in Linux?

I am trying something like this:

```
aws glacier get-job-output --account-id - --vault-name newone --job-id "VO0zQ7Uvl0LxpG6ZDBMTsRK2td2Sq3BwqVpq_hWVcfgv7UrVC1l3B1PUidrjj85fwihUXwReYR3wcYLHU98ObhOEP5yE" mydata.txt.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

Glacier does not store file names so in the response to [get-job-output](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glacier/get-job-output.html) you will see `ArchiveId` instead. You can use an archive's `ArchiveDescription` field to store filenames and other metadata. Third-party Glacier management tools like [FastGlacier](https://fastglacier.com/fastglacier-metadata-format.aspx) do this to make them a bit more user-friendly.

See: [How do I use the AWS CLI to view the contents of my Amazon Glacier vault?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cli-glacier-vault/)

Comment: Actually i want to list data only on Linux machine. And fast glacier is used only for downloading and listing data on windows machine. Is there any way to do same thing through any scripting or API.